# using krealloc multiple times vs. allocating a large-enough space once

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

When coding an extension to the Linux kernel(e.g. adding a new system call) I am to maintain data size of which can dynamically change during runtime.

There are two alternative approaches I may take. First is allocating an initial space using **kmalloc**, and reallocating *when necessary* using **krealloc**. The second is allocating a *large-enough* space with **kmalloc** and never having to resize it. You may assume that I have an upper bound to my data size and "*large-enough*" is a well-defined value, say **N**. I was wondering whether there are any guidelines as to which approach one should take while coding in kernel space.

The tradeoff between the time overhead by multiple reallocations and allocating a large space is obvious, even when coding in user space. But my question asks whether there is a suggested way to go. And if there isn't any, and it depends on the specific circumstances, how large an **N** value should be considered as too much space, or how frequent calls to krealloc should be deemed too many, leading one to choose the other method?

Comment: It's not the answer to your question, but just a little practical advice: if re-allocating is gonna happen often enough, forget about re-allocating. Allocate one big chunk once, and reuse it later. Prefer `vmalloc()` if you don't really need physically contiguous memory. Sticking to this rule, you will avoid memory fragmentation and all associated consequences. If you still decide to go with `krealloc()` -- take into the account [its coorect usage](https://tapaswenipathak.wordpress.com/2015/01/13/faults-in-linux-kernel-3-x-wrong-use-of-krealloc/).

Comment: @SamProtsenko I was considering to reallocate only when the current capacity was insufficient, similar to some c++ Standard Template Library containers(e.g. std::vector) doubling the capacity when it is insufficient. I was initially in favor of allocating a single large chunk, as well. Yet, as far as I observed, space is considered a more significant resource in kernel programming. That's why I asked whether a more specific set of guidelines/principles existed for kernel programming.

Comment: @SamProtsenko By the way, thanks for the krealloc usage warning that's featured in the link you shared.

Comment: @ilim, by the way, Fibonacci approach would be better (imagine case when you need 2^n + 1 elements only).